# how to call a static JS file from an EJS without mime block nosniff Error?

Tags: javascript, express, static, ejs

trying to understand why mime nosniff is blocking my static JS file?
even though its been defined as "text/javascript"

using a simple express app to call the route of the EJS.
here are the files

SERVER:

```
const express = require ("express");
const { render } = require("express/lib/response");
const app = express();
const path = require('path'); 
app.use(express.static('public'))
     
     
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //enabling ejs
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname ,'/views')) 
     
    app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
        res.render('test');
    })
     
     
    app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000!")
    })
```

EJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content-type="application/javascript" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hey do you think this could work?
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geojson1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Static JS file

```
const inside = "in the JS file ";
    console.log(inside)
```

getting the usual:
"The resource from “http://localhost:3000/geojson1.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

Comment: I recreated your setup here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-https-nqjo7?file=/src/index.js Works fine.

Comment: I guess I'm not running the server in the correct directory? it gives me the same error. I forgot to mention-its on my local computer. I've seen that your code works. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Hi @Arush did you got what is the issue I am also stucked in same Error from 2 days, My issue is actually whenever I give route as `/login` everything works fine but when I chage route to anything else like `/user/login` I got this error. 
If you already got the root cause of this error then please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I don't remember exactly, but i don't think you can call js script that is in a ejs. since we are routing via servers, the security measures are to prevent us to load anything from a file that isn't a known route. or something like that. but i could be wrong.